# fmp4 for hevc in hls - SRS server

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, hevc, simple-realtime-server

When using the `feature/h265` branch of SRS server, the segment files of HLS is always mpegts, whatever publishing by RTMP or SRT.

It works for VLC, but fail for Apple Safari, because Safari requires fMP4 segment file of HLS. But Safari is the premier usage for hevc in H5.

Does SRS supports HLS with fMP4?

Answer (score 1):

SRS doesn't support fMP4 with H.265 for HLS, and there is no plan right now, at 2021.12.

> Note: SRS supports H.265/HEVC in MPEGTS for HLS, but it seems doesn't work in Safari.

There is a workaround, use FFmpeg to covert RTMP to HLS with H.265, please read [here](https://superuser.com/a/1416549).